# Auto Update PackageVersion when pack

Tags: c#, git, nuget

I have two big Solutions containing Projects which in the end should be converted in NugetPackages.

```
Solution1:
    Sol1.Core -> Sol1.[version].nupkg
    Sol1.Repository.Abstract -> Sol1.Repository.Abstract.[version].nupkg
    Sol1.Repository -> Sol1.Repository.[version].nupkg
    Sol1.Service.Abstract -> Sol1.Service.Abstract.[version].nupkg
    Sol1.Service -> Sol1.Service.[version].nupkg
    Sol1.WebAPI
```

There are the following dependencies, between the packages.

```
Sol1.Repository.Abstract depends on
   Sol1.Core
Sol1.Repository depends on
   Sol1.Core
   Sol1.Repository.Abstract
Sol1.Service.Abstract depends on
   Sol1.Core
Sol1.Service depends on
   Sol1.Core
   Sol1.Service.Abstract
Sol1.WebAPI depends on
   Sol1.Core
   Sol1.Repository.Abstract
   Sol1.Repository
   Sol1.Service
   Sol1.Service.Abstract
```

The code of the backend should be shared, with other applications, therefore they should be shared pushed to a Nuget Repository to be available to other.
The problem is, if there is a change in on Project, I need to update the version number of that project and the version number of all projects depending on it.
This is always complicate, because I have to go into every Project File, update the Version number and then  go to the depending projects and do the same.

I found the true Attribute inside the RestSharp Project and think it works with Tag using MinVersion on the git Repository.
But this don't work for me because all my Projects are stored inside on Git-Repository.

Is there a way to implement this simply?